# Do I need to disclose traffic tickets on my "Background Investigation Authorization" form?

Tags: new-job, united-states, background-check

Simple enough really. I got an offer, I accepted it, they are starting the onboarding process.

The form says,

> Have you ever been convicted of, plead guilty, or "no contest" to a
>   crime that has or has not been expunged or removed from your record?
>   If yes, please explain: (Make sure to include the city/state/county
>   and the year the crime occurred for each conviction.)

I was in a wreck a couple months back, long story, got a ticket. I have not yet finished driver safety school, so it is still on my record. Is this considered a crime? Do they want this disclosed? Will I look bad if I don't mention it?

Comment: Most people would not call that a crime.  It is just an infraction.  Pretty sure they only mean misdemeanor and felony.  Some traffic violations are misdemeanors or felonies.

Comment: Why are you asking us and not the court where you have to settle your ticket? Whether a traffic ticket is an infraction, a misdemeanor or a felony depends on what took place including whether you got someone killed or inflicted serious property damage or were driving while intoxicated or engaged in reckless driving. Only that court or your lawyer can give you an answer that's definitive for your locale. Voting to close on the ground that the answer is locale-specific.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan - 1) I didn't know that. 2) The people here are more likely to have these forms pass over their desks and know what they expect.

Comment: "The people here are more likely to have these forms pass over their desks and know what they expect." So what? What does their story have in common with yours?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan - No, not people with common stories. I mean HR and hiring managers.

Comment: What are you trying to say, that they don't take the forms and how you fill them seriously?

Comment: I probably wouldn't, but you skipped over the reason for the ticket by saying, "long story," so it's hard to give you advice about this. Plus, I think this might be an off-topic question.

Comment: I would suggest go and meet the HR personally. You can ask these question directly to them. They will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have you ever been convicted of, plead guilty, or "no contest" to a
>   crime that has or has not been expunged or removed from your record?
>   If yes, please explain: (Make sure to include the city/state/county
>   and the year the crime occurred for each conviction.)

Always err on disclosing too much.

If they ask for everything that falls into this category, and you disclose those that occupy a gray area then they with tither use that to determine if you have a clean enough background, or they will ignore it.

If you don't disclose them, and they find it, they may assume that you tried to hide them. If they think it was a gray area they may not penalize you for not reporting it, but they could still be concerned that you didn't report it.

> I have not yet finished driver safety school, so it is still on my
>   record.

If they think the incident is reportable by you, they will still expect you to report it after it is removed from your record. They said "that has or has not been expunged or removed from your record". So even years from now they will want you to report it. That tells me that they want you to tell them those things that will be hard to find.